# Relationship between big-Oh and little-Oh

Tags: convergence, bounds

I'm reading Wu, J. (2014), Restoring monotonic power in Wald/LM-type tests.

At a certain point in his derivations, an expresion turns out to be $=O_p(\frac{1}{T^{3/10}h^{5/10}}+T^{2/10}h^{20/10})$, where $T$ is the sample size (the paper is about time series tests) and $h$ is the bandwidth of a kernel estimator he is proposing.

Earlier in the paper, the author makes the following assumptions: $h \rightarrow 0$, $T^3h^5 \rightarrow \infty$, and $Th^{10} \rightarrow 0$ as $T \rightarrow \infty$.

From the $O_p$ order and these assumptions, the author concludes that the expression is actually $o_p(1)$. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1364444

Comment: It is easy to show that, if $X_T = O_p(\gamma_T)$ where $\gamma_T \to 0$ then you automatically have $X_T = o_p(1)$. The Big-oh notation implies that $X_T = Z_T \gamma_T$ where $Z_T$ is bounded in probability, and you can use the definition of a random variable being bounded in probability to show that $X_T \stackrel{p}{\to} 0$ so that $X_T = o_p(1)$.